# Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed error Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am getting an error when running the migration command.

This is the admin table schema

```
Schema::create('admin', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->increments('id');
                $table->integer('user_id')->unique();

                $table->timestamps();

                $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
            });
```

And the other is the user table that comes with laravel installation.

I want to create a foreign key for user_id but it gives error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all all, make sure you're executing this migration after the `users` one.

Also, change this:

```
$table->integer('user_id')->unique();
```

To:

```
$table->unsignedInteger('user_id');
```

Comment: Thnx it works but is it compulsory to add unsignedInteger to the user_id ?

Comment: @Raj yes, you need to use `unsignedInteger()` or `integer()->unsigned()`